# object cannot be cast from DBNULL to ther types

Tags: c#-4.0

I'am using GetOrdinal in my code. the code

```
mastxtDateEnded_Edit.Text =
        Convert.ToDateTime(cursor.GetValue(cursor.GetOrdinal("DateEnded")))
               .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));

Error: object cannot be cast from DBNULL to ther types.
```

Comment: There is no question in you  post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`IsDBNull` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dbdatareader.isdbnull%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check for the null value:

```
int index = cursor.GetOrdinal("DateEnded")
mastxtDateEnded_Edit.Text =
  cursor.IsDBNull(index) ?
    String.Empty :
    ((DateTime)(cursor.GetValue(index))).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```