# Using !DBNull.Value

Tags: c#

I'm having problem with this code:

```
if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(mastxtDateEnded_Edit.Text))
{
    //mastxtDateEnded_Edit.Text = Convert.ToDateTime(reader[28]).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
    mastxtDateEnded_Edit.Text = Convert.ToString(reader[28]).ToString();
}
```

the output:

92/91/974

Comment: What kind of control is mastxtDateEnded_Edit.Text?

Comment: What is the problem with it?

Comment: Also, it doesn't really help to do a `.ToString()` on a `string`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24220254/object-cannot-be-cast-from-dbnull-to-ther-types.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to set the TextBox (or maskedtextbox) with the content of field 28 only if it is not NULL, then you should write something like

```
mastxtDateEnded_Edit.Text = reader.IsDBNull(28) 
                            ? string.Empty 
                            : reader[28].ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

Your code doesn't seem to be right. A TextBox control Text property is never null. It is the reader that could have a field that contains the DBNull.Value and, if you want to set the textbox usually you check with IsDBNull and use an empty string to substitute the null value.

By the way, this is exactly the same thing that has been told to you on your first question. Something that doesn't work here?

Comment: I try your code their is an error: No overload for method 'ToString' takes '1' arguments.